# strange s:url behavier

Tags: url, struts2

i just found something funny, i cannot explain it. can someone explain it.

I have define a url in my jsp file

```
<s:url var="test" action="Home.action" escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name="departYear" value="2006"/>
    <s:param name="homeTown" value="lanzhou"/>
</s:url>
<p><s:property value="test"/></p>
```

and the result is `/path/to/action/Home.action?departYear=2006` and if i change the second parameter `<s:param name="homeTown" value="123456"/>`, then it shows me properly with `/path/to/action/Home.action?departYear=2006&homeTown=123456` I havn't tried to print the `url` and it works always fine with more parameters. it doesn't triggered any problem at all. I just curious, why it doesn't work with `s:property`.

btw, i changed the order of 2 parameters too, and it doesn't show the parameter in the url either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tag-syntax.html)... it says that **`value` is an Object**, not a string.

`<s:param name="homeTown" value="lanzhou"/>` would call the `getLanzhou()` method of your action class to try and populate the value.

What you want is `<s:param name="homeTown" value="%{'lanzhou'}"/>`

`<s:param name="departYear" value="2006"/>` works because non-String attribute types are not parsed, but evaluated directly as an expression.